# How to send paramenter in jquery syntax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want click the button call function with parameter but i don't know how to write syntax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ShowMap').on('click', initialize);
})
function initialize(value) {
    alert(value);
}
```

> if change code for code down code work but after load page function called

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ShowMap').on('click', initialize("test"));
})
```

> how to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't send the function as a parameter, it immediately executes the function and sends the *result* (which is `undefined`) as the parameter:

```
$('#ShowMap').on('click', initialize("test"));
```

Instead, wrap it in a function to be the parameter:

```
$('#ShowMap').on('click', function () { initialize("test"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass another function as argument and inside that function call the desired function
`$('#ShowMap').on('click', initialize("test"));` will not send function as argument it will send the return value of the `initialize` which is `undefined`

```js
function initialize(value){
  console.log(value);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ShowMap').on('click',() => initialize("test"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ShowMap">Show Map</button>
```

Comment: @Zanyar J.Ahmed accept the answer if you are satisfied